# Upload built artifact from another step

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I have a question about my bitbucket pipeline. I have set up all the variables but I am not able to copy the built docker image to another location in the next pipeline step.

```yaml
 preview:
      - step:
          name: Build Docker image for preview branch and save as .tar
          caches:
            - docker
          size: 2x #2x memory flag
          services:
            - docker
          script:
            - echo "Building Docker image for preview branch..."
            - docker build -f ./src/API/Dockerfile -t $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG .
            - docker save -o $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG.tar $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG
      - step:
          name: Upload Docker image as artifact
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file:0.7.1
              variables:
                BITBUCKET_USERNAME: $BITBUCKET_USERNAME
                BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD: $BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD
                FILENAME: "$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG.tar"
                DIRECTORY: "downloads"
```

It yields the following error:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for bitbucketpipelines/bitbucket-upload-file:0.7.1
INFO: Executing the pipe...
✖ File Application.tar doesn't exist.
```

(docker build is successful)

How can I copy the resulted docker built .tar file to a new location?

Answer (score 0):

Artifacts that should be copied from former step onto subsequent steps must be declared with the [`artifacts`](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/step-options/#Artifacts) key.

With your example:

```yaml
pipelines:
  branches:
    preview:
      - step:
          name: Build Docker image for preview branch and save as .tar
          caches:
            - docker
          services:
            - docker
          script:
            - echo "Building Docker image for preview branch..."
            - docker build -f ./src/API/Dockerfile -t $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG .
            - docker save -o dockerimage.tar $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG
          artifacts:
            - dockerimage.tar
      - step:
          name: Upload Docker image as artifact
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file:0.7.1
              variables:
                BITBUCKET_USERNAME: $BITBUCKET_USERNAME
                BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD: $BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD
                FILENAME: dockerimage.tar
                DIRECTORY: "downloads"
```

You won't be able to interpolate variables in there so you should settle for a hard name or putting all images in a subfolder (then, declare `artifacts: ["build/*.tar"]` and whatnot)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am testing currently.

Comment: It saves the files as artificat, which is great. Now I've got the following error

```
  File "/pipe.py", line 117, in read
    with open(self.filename, self.mode) as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'application.tar'

```

How to solve that?

Is it easier with CURL?

Thank you again!

Comment: You should chmod the file to something like 644

Answer (score 0):

had to change the filepermissions before with **chmod**

```yaml
services:
  - docker
script:
  - echo "Building Docker image for preview branch..."
  - docker build -f ./src/API/Dockerfile -t $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG .
  - docker save -o $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG.tar $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG
  - chmod 644 $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG.tar
artifacts:
  - application.tar
```

Hope this helps other people too!